# How to reuse pending comments after git commit fail?

Tags: git, git-commit

I use external editor to fill comments for "git commit", if by some reason commit fails all comments disappear. Is there some place where my comments for commit that's failed are stored ?

Is there any specific git command to reuse such pending comments or repeat commit with pending comments ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;dr:

1. Run `git commit -eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

or

1. Run (only once): `git config --global alias.commit-reuse 'commit -eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'`
2. Run (whenever you want to reuse a message): `git commit-reuse`

---

If you write your commit message in an external editor, the message is stored in `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`. Even if the commit subsequently fails, the message will be stored there. The next time you do `git commit`, however, git resets the file and opens the editor there.

You can use the `-F` option to tell git to use the contents of an existing file as your commit message. After your failed commit, you can do `git commit -F .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, and git will immediately create the commit with the message that is stored in that file. However, note that *commented lines will be included* in the commit message if you do this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Explicit paths specified without -i nor -o; assuming --only paths...
# ...
```

You can additionally use the `-e` option to ask git to open the file in an editor. Commit messages made with the editor will never include commented lines. This will also allow you to edit the message before creating the commit. So, simply use `git commit -eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` after a failed `git commit`. Note, however, that this command fails if `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` does not exist, for example if you just cloned the repo.

If you don't want to remember the `-eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` option, you can create an alias within git. You can permanently add an alias by running

```sh
git config --global alias.commit-reuse 'commit -eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
```

From now on, you can write `git commit-reuse` whenever you want to reuse the message of a failed commit. If you want to remove the alias again, you can remove the relevant line from `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: I just find out that last commit message is stored under .git folder in the file "COMMIT_EDITMSG" even if commit has failed

Comment: @sim Wow. That's really cool! I think you should post that solution yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately git does nothing special with file COMMIT_EDITMSG when we need to reuse it, hence "git commit -e -F .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" is the most suitable, as it allows edit message and also excludes comments after save

Comment: Thanks, the `-e` is a nice move too. I updated my answer, though this is really *your* own answer of course.